# Comparing coordinates between two matrices in r and outputting ones which are the same

Tags: r, matrix, compare, comparison

I have 2 data frames each consisting of rows of co-ordinates namely x,y,z

These data frames are of different length

I would like to be able to use one data frame as a reference and search the other for any coordinates that match in **all** 3 positions

I would then like these coordinates to be written to another data frame

i.e.
data frame one:

```
[1,]  1  2  3
[2,]  2  3  3
[3,]  1  2  4
[4,]  4  2  5
```

data frame two:

```
[1,]  3  2  3
[2,]  1  1  2  
[3,]  2  3  3
[4,]  1  2  3
```

and I would like this to return

```
[1,]  2  3  3
[2,]  1  2  3
```

the ones that match

i.e. I want it to, not just check rows of the same number but all rows in the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `intersect` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(as.data.frame(m1) , as.data.frame(m2))
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  2  3  3
#2  1  2  3
```

Or you can use

```
mNew <- rbind(m1,m2)
mNew[duplicated(mNew),]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    3
#[2,]    1    2    3
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(c(1,2,1,4, 2,3,2,4, 3,3,4,5), ncol=3)
 m2 <- matrix(c(3,1,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,3), ncol=3)
```

Comment: Returns: 'data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
' However I know at least 3 rows overlap??

Comment: @T_stats_3 I am not getting that on the dataset created.  Have you tried the second method?  I am using R 3.1.1.

Comment: This is on a different, much larger data set, that was only a fabricated example? The second method seems to have solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: @T_stats_3 Looks like I called the `dplyr` `intersect` instead of the `base R` intersect and that makes the difference.  I was able to replicate the `dataframe with 0 columns and 0 rows` with `base R intersect`.